# laravel url not working properly

Tags: .htaccess, laravel

i have created a project in laravel (
    `http://mysiteip/~productdemo/yelp/`
).The url is not working with out `index.php`.
My current url is

```
http://mysiteip/~productdemo/yelp/explore"
```

but its not working.If i put

```
http://mysiteip/~productdemo/yelp/index.php/explore"
```

it's working.How I can solve the problem please help me on that.
My current `.htacess` file has the code like the following

```
RewriteEngine On
# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Comment: have you enabled rewrite module, I'm assuming of course you are using Apache.

Comment: YOur htaccess file in the yelp directory?

Comment: @lozadaOmr..yes i have enabled rewrite module.

Comment: @jonLin ,yes its in yelp directory

Comment: And you don't have `explore` directory or file in `yelp` ?

Comment: Check your server config if you're using apache, make sure you have the AllowOverride all in the <Directory> section of your site config

Answer (score 0):

From Laravel Documentarion.

**Apache**

The framework ships with a public/.htaccess file that is used to allow URLs without index.php. If you use Apache to serve your Laravel application, be sure to enable the mod_rewrite module.

If the .htaccess file that ships with Laravel does not work with your Apache installation, try this one:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Source: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/installation#pretty-urls